# DSE Enterprise - When will Indexes on polygons be supported?

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-enterprise-graph

I am using DSE Enterprise 5.0.4, and I need to ask a query on polygons, like which polygons are within a polygon?.
Indexes on polygons are not supported at the moment. Got null pointer ex.

Comment: one option is to use the DSE Search (apache solr powered) polygons and do searh intercept queries instead of the native DSE types.

Comment: I am using DSE graph, and want to ask a graph query with polygon vertex. I don't need DSE for using Solr (4.10), I can install solr 6 instead.